# Kendo datasource model - difference between _data[0] and get(0)

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to know the difference between

```
$("#uploadedFile").val(e.files[0].name);
var model = $("#blueprint_listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource.get(0);        
model.set("filename", $("#uploadedFile").val());
```

And

```
$("#uploadedFile").val(e.files[0].name);
var model = $("#blueprint_listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource._data[0];        
model.set("filename", $("#uploadedFile").val());
```

I am having an editable listview with a upload.

And the above code is written on the success event on the kendo upload.

The second code works fine for insert and update.

However, the first code works fine for insert, but for update it is showing an error which says - "The model is not defined"

I was wondering what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-get), `get` retrieves a record with the corresponding id. This way, when a new record is inserted it seems that it has the default id of 0, that's why `get(0) === _data[0]` but when you are updating the listview, a "real" id (>=1) is given to your new line and there is no longer an item with id=0, so `model` is then null.

On the other side, the internal method `_data` is an array with all the lines of your list view put in the order of their position in the listview. But if you want to access to this property, the equivalent "public" method is [`at`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-at) :

```
$("#blueprint_listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource._data[0] === 
   $("#blueprint_listview").data("kendoListView").dataSource.at(0); // allways true
```